# Redirect to https as well as removing .html (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I would like to force ssl on my website as well as removing the file extensions at the end of my urls this page for example `http://www.site.com/image.html` would be made `https://www.site.com/image` I already have the part which redirects to https however can not think of a way to remove the second part I also would have no idea how to add this to the .htaccess and have it work. The code I have been using is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I would greatly appreciate some help and apologies for needing to be spoonfed as I am a total newb.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: This works however my website features an index of file ie: https://www.site.com/images/image.jpg the .htaccess removes the .jpg however if I go to the images page I get an index of the files on the page is there a way to avoid this or will I have to forget removing the file extensions?

Comment: @AlanFletcher Add an htaccess file in the `/images/` directory that has `Options -Indexes` in it.